# Add a array-element in Smarty-Template

Tags: php, templates, variables, smarty

is there a way to add a element to an Array inside a Smarty-Template?

Example:

I want to do something like:

```
$myArray[] = array('val1' => 'aaa', 'val2' => 'bbb');
```

But I need to do that inside the template.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

```
{assign 'myArray' ['val1' => 'aaa', 'val2' => 'bbb']}
```

or

```
{assign var=myArray value=['val1' => 'aaa', 'val2' => 'bbb']}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that, unless you're working with smarty versions older than 3 (and even if it's possible it's not recommended). {php} is deprecated from smarty and removed/disabled in newer versions for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

As explained at http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

```
{$myArray[]=['val1' => 'aaa', 'val2' => 'bbb']}
```